# Creating Custom fields from Flex (Salesforce)

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, metadata, salesforce

I'm trying to CREATE custom fields from flex, but I'm having hard time finding the correct syntax.

Below is the piece of code that I'm using and it's resulting in error "**sf:INVALID_TYPE INVALID_TYPE: null objects not allowed in create/update request**"

```
    var con:Connection = new Connection();
    var lRequest:LoginRequest = new LoginRequest();
    lRequest.username = username1.text;
    lRequest.password = password1.text;
    lRequest.callback = new mx.rpc.Responder(createFields, loginFault);
    con.login(lRequest);

    //CreateFields Method ....
    var externalIdField:CustomField = new CustomField();
    externalIdField.label = 'ProductionId';
    externalIdField.type = FieldType.ID;
    externalIdField._length = 18;
    externalIdField.externalId = true;
    externalIdField.unique = true;

    var customObjectVar:CustomObject = new CustomObject();
    customObjectVar["type"] = "Account";
    customObjectVar.addField(externalIdField);

    var objarray:Array = [];
    objarray[0]=customObjectVar;
    con.updateObject(objarray,new mx.rpc.Responder(saveresults,sfdcFailure));
```

Tried below alternate way (as suggested by Simon), that too results in error

> "soapenv:Client Element
>   {http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata}type
>   invalid at this location"

```
    var externalIdField:CustomField = new CustomField();
    externalIdField.fullName = 'Account.ProductionId__c';
    externalIdField.type = FieldType.STRING;
    externalIdField._length = 18;
    externalIdField.externalId = true;
    externalIdField.unique = true;

    var objarray:Array = [];
    objarray[0]=externalIdField;
    con.updateObject(objarray,new mx.rpc.Responder(saveresults,sfdcFailure));
```

`

Answer (score 1):

To create fields you would pass a CustomField instance to the metadata api create call (its not clear from your code what `con` is), in addition to the fields you've set, you need to set the fullName (e.g. Account.ProductionId__c in this case)

Comment: @superfell please check above post, i tried the way you suggested and it seems I'm missing something ...as that too is resulting in error. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the actual generated soap message.

Comment: is con generated from the metadata WSDL? there's no updateObject call in the metadata API (perhaps you're mixing the enterprise or partner APIs with the metadata API?)

Comment: I haven't consumed any wsdl. I'm using the native salesforce.com flex toolkit. I just went ahead and created a flex project and added following libraries in project references:
f3_common.swc
f3_toolkit.swc
f3_flex.swc

Comment: I haven't used the toolkit, but a quick scan of the docs seems to indicate that it only implements a very small subset of the metadata API.

Comment: so what's the work around? I'm not sure whether I should continue using toolkit or should i import metadata wsdl (if that's possible). Please guide!